# Replacing apostrophe if not surrounded by other apostrophe

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm looking for a way to find and search through all ' characters in a string. I intend to replace them only if they aren't preceeding another ' character. How should I go about this without entering a cycle "for" and searching through all characters in c#?

Comment: Could you add some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with SQL queries by any chance...?

Comment: What's wrong with a loop? Otherwise you have regex, but that probably doesn't gain you much other than it'll be fewer lines.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); why do you want to “replace apostrophe if not surrounded by other apostrophe”?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: Less code for the same result is reason enough in my book. I do appreciate your point, though: the fact that you don't see the loop in code doesn't mean it'll perform any better. At some point you have to look through all the characters.

Comment: Yes it actually does @maccettura, as it's the command that'll run through dynamic sql. Basically I intend to replace for instance "Select * from tables where name = 'apple' " into "Select * from tables where name = ''apple'' ". Turn one apostrophe, that isn't followed by another one, into two.

Comment: @E.T how is this SQL dynamic?  From user input?  This sounds like you will have massive SQL injection vulnerabilities...

Comment: All you're trying to do is replace apostrophes with quotation marks in a SQL query string? First of all, why even bother, and second of all, what's wrong with a simple `String.Replace`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I agree, although I think it depends. In this case it's fine because the regex is simple, but if it were elaborate and painful to read, I'd opt for a simple loop (assuming the loop is simple enough and performance is reasonable of course). I'm mainly getting at the fact that loops != terrible performance.

Comment: @Abion47 - I agree with your "why bother?" (also that it's probably the wrong approach for whatever is going on here), but how would you get away with a `String.Replace` without wiping out the instances of `''`?

Comment: It's intended to run locally so I don't think that'll be a problem. It's intended for the user to insert their sql code to be passed down as a parameter for an sp to do additional tasks with it (including running it)

Comment: @E.T.: That definitely sounds like you're looking for the wrong solution to the problem. Just as one example, what if you had `Select * from tables where name = 'Tom's apple'` or `Select * from tables where name = 'Tom''s apple'`. Would you want both of those to become `Select * from tables where name = ''Tom''s apple''`? When constructing dynamic code (like SQL), you need to encode each input based on the context into which it's being injected.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior My native language does not use apostrophe and as I said, it's to be used locally, I don't think it'll be a problem.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior And then there's the case of `Select * from tables where name = ''`

Comment: @E.T.: If your native language does not use an apostrophe, why do you want to ignore double-apostrophes?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.  As it is, if you have more than one single quote in a row, it removes one of them (so that ''' becomes '').  That's how I read your "spec".

It does "cycle" through all the characters - sorry.  At some point, whether you use Replace or a Regex or do it yourself like this code, something is going to cycle through your string character by character.  Here, at least, you have control over it.  It uses a StringBuilder because, well, it's a string-builder (and StringBuilders are pretty fast at this).

```
  private string RemoveSingleQuotes(string fromString)
  {
      var buffer = new StringBuilder(fromString.Length);
      const char quote = '\'';
      bool quoteCluster = false;
      foreach (var c in fromString)
      {
          if (c == quote && quoteCluster)
          {
              buffer.Append(c);
          }
          else if (c == quote)
          {
              quoteCluster = true;
          }
          else
          {
              buffer.Append(c);
              quoteCluster = false;
          }
      }
      return buffer.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: I think OP's trying to *replace* single-quotes, not *remove* them. Besides that, this code wouldn't work as expected. It'll remove the first of any series of quotes.

Comment: Replacing, rather than removing, affects a single line of code - he never said what he wanted to replace them with, so I picked the empty string,  His "spec" said " I intend to replace them only if they aren't preceding another ' character".  That's what this does. Not doing that is likely another line or two of code (toggling the `quoteCluster` flag off after the first `buffer.Append(c);` call).